# datepicker parsing date issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, datetime, datepicker

I've the next problem:
when I recieve date from server, I want to format it via datepicker, but datepicker throws exceptions, cause it can't parse the date.
here is my date, whcih comes from server(obj.value):
`08.20.2012 19:01:32`
and here is code via which I try to parse this date:
`$.datepicker.formatDate('dd.MM.yy', new Date(obj.value));`
I use MM cause I need the full name of the month.
and here is output after parsing:
`NaN.NaN.NaN`
so how to get rid of this exception?

Comment: so the JS and jQuey are so weak? pfff

Comment: It is weakness of concrete IE8 implementation of Date object constructor. jQuery is not about dates, it is about DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change you date (`obj.value`) to a valid JavaScript date format. Best if you can do on the server side.

If you want to do it on client side you need to replace `.` with `/` so you get `08/20/2012 19:01:32` instead of `08.20.2012 19:01:32`.

```
new Date(obj.value.replace(/\./g, '/'))
```

Comment: it's unneeded load for server

Comment: "it's unneeded load for server ", hu?

Comment: suggest 1000 000 users connect the page. server load and time cost money. and it's so simple, that JS is helpless? ;)

Comment: Well as I said, you can parse the date on you client side code (in javascript) as in my answer above.

Comment: it adds one more year )) console.log($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.MM.yy', new Date(obj.value.replace(/\./g, '/')  ))); gives me 08.August.2013

Comment: What does console.log(new Date(obj.....) gives you? Also I think you need to first set the date and the set the format. See documentation http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: console.log(new Date(obj.value)); says Date {Invalid Date}

Comment: Sorry, I meant. console.log(new Date(obj.value.replace(/\./g, '/')));

Comment: it says Date {Thu Aug 08 2013 19:01:32 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)} why day is 08 and not 20 ??

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse a date in JavaScript, this is completely implementation depend. It seems that many browsers are unable to parse your provided string. You will have to do either of two thing:

- Provide a valid string.
- Call a Date constructor.

Also see this answer: [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse/2587398#2587398)

Answer (score 0):

`Date()` receives `integers` and `strings` only. You should work the value of obj before passing it to `Date()`

Comment: but 08.20.2012 19:01:32  is a String

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have control over what is returned by the server, the simplest approach by far is to return a UNIX timestamp instead of a formatted date string.

UNIX epoch and Javascript epoch are the same (00:00 1 Jan 1970) but UNIX timestamps are in seconds while javascript's `Date` object works with milliseconds.

So :

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd.MM.yy', new Date(obj.value * 1000));
```

As you can see **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgh8Q/)**, obj.value can be integer or string. In the case of a string, javascript's automatic type conversion looks after the multiplication.

Comment: the incoming date is in the format above and NOT in the seconds from 1970

Comment: UNIX timestamp is pretty well the *de facto* format for transmission of date/time. Something to remember for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to reformat your  incoming datestring into something thats parsable by javascript Date() function. If you have no control of the format coming from you server i would suggest something along the lines of

```
var incDate, dateString, timeString, dateSplit, timeSplit;
incDate = obj.value.split(" ");
dateString = incDate[0];
timeString = incDate[1];
dateSplit  = dateString.split(".");
timeSplit = timeString.split(":");
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd.MM.yy', new Date(dateSplit[2],dateSplit[0]-1,dateSplit[1],timeSplit[0],timeSplit[1],timeSplit[2]));
```

Comment: it says the date is 08.August.2013

Comment: Are you sure you entered the dateSplit parts correctly as 2,0,1 the Date object requires it be entered in year,month,day descending order and if you had put 2,1,0 (2012,20,8) it would take 20 months and convert it to 1 year 8 months resulting in the 8/8/2013 date your currently seeing. Also please ensure you do not forget the `-1` on the month part as this is actually a 0-11 value (month 0 = january)

Comment: I've just pasted your code and it doesn't work, then I added '-1' to dateSplit[2] and year is 2012. but why the day is 08 and not 20 ??

Comment: are you absolutly positive that the date your receiving is in the format `08.20.2012 19:01:32` and not `20.08.2012 19:01:32` the only thing i can think of is your actually receiving the latter. in which case you would need to adjust the dateSplit order to 2,1,0

Comment: in fact, i don't need the day, but I was intersted why it worked so :)